# Firefox developer tools adding a new rule?

Tags: css, developer-tools, firefox-developer-tools

I decided to try out the built in Firefox Developer Tools. Seems to be nice, but...

I can't find out how to add a new rule to the CSS from Inspector/Rules. By that I mean ".my-new-rule" not just the "element" rule that is open by default.

**FINAL EDIT: This is now possible with the latest Firefox update.**

Comment: Use the 'Style Editor' from the 'Web Developer' menu in the 'Tools' dropdown. Or make a right click in the css inspector an select 'New Rule'.

Comment: Sorry, can't seem to find the New Rule option...

Comment: Oops, silly me used the css inspector from firebug. Sorry too.

Comment: +1 for adding on the edits. They will help people in the future who have the same question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Update:

**As of FF 33.00 it is now possible to add new CSS rules using the inspector!**

---

It is not possible to use the inspector to create new CSS rules with out a browser add-on (see comment below).
Just use the style editor. Type anywhere to make a new rule:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks. But is there no way to add it to through the inspector? If not I guess I'll just have to change my ways :)

Comment: No, I do not think you can add new rules in the inspector. :(  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector

Comment: You can't currently but this is being actively worked on and will ship in Firefox 33 or 34.

Comment: @canuckistani Okay, looking forward to that.;)

Comment: "Not possible" is not entirely true. I wrote an addon for it and there are probably others - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/devtools-tweaks/

Answer (score 3):

As of Firefox 33 (in nightly right now https://nightly.mozilla.org/), this works.

When you have a node selected in the inspector, you can click on any of the selectors in the "Rules" sidebar to edit them.

Comment: but can you add new rules?

Comment: This just landed in Firefox 33 too! Right-click in the "Rules" sidebar of the inspector and choose "Add rule".